# mysql delimiter is not working from command line

Tags: mysql

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test;

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER UPDATE ON users_reviews
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select * from users_reviews;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

returns server 500 error in phpmyadmin and custom `delimiter` is not working from command line. MySQL 5.1.17
(works fine on windows)

Comment: I believe you don't need the `;` after `END`.

Comment: when you bash or cron etc the escape sequences are way different. Until you figure that out, do a test with the stuff in a .sql file and `<` the file in on the command line. Those are your two options, basically

Comment: it executes right after select * from users_reviews; looks like delimiter does not take affect

Comment: I tested with sql file already, no errors and doesn't work. I tested on other servers and it works fine. My MYSQL is 5.1.17

Comment: these things aren't portable 100%. There are various posts about certain versions of phpmyadmin not behaving the way you would like

Comment: Wait... are you intentionally trying to return a result set from a trigger?

Comment: And the worst thing is an upvote!

Comment: @Joe before we try to help you, because this is the classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) what are you trying to accomplish with this trigger?

Comment: I'm not trying to return a recordset, this is just an example

Comment: I'm trying to update kind of caching table AFTER UPDATE. Complete trigger body I have here is just fine and runs on other platforms including Linux and Windows without any issues. Just this version of MySQL behaves weird and I know that the reason for it is delimited that gets ignored with first ";"